# How to check strictly increasing and decreasing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I solved an exercise in javascript but I'm not very happy with my solution and I couldn't find a better one.

Problem: check if an array have a starting subarray strictly increasing and an ending subarray strictly decreasing. Each array has at least 3 elements.

Examples:

```js
checkSledJump([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]) // true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
checkSledJump([0, 1, 0])       // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
checkSledJump([0, 3, 2, 1])    // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
checkSledJump([0, 1000, 1])    // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing

checkSledJump([2, 4, 4, 6, 2])       // false: [4,4] isn't strictly increasing or decreasing
checkSledJump([1, 2, 3])             // false: only increasing
checkSledJump([3, 2, 1])             // false: only decreasing
checkSledJump([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]) // false: increasing then decreasing then increasing
```

My solution:

```js
function checkSledJump(heights) {
  let max = Math.max(...heights);
  let maxIndex = heights.indexOf(max);
  if (maxIndex === 0 || maxIndex === heights.length-1) return false
  
  let strictlyIncreasing = heights.slice(0, maxIndex+1)
  let strictlyDecreasing = heights.slice(maxIndex);

  for(let i = 0; i < strictlyIncreasing.length - 1; i++)
    if(!(strictlyIncreasing[i] < strictlyIncreasing[i+1])) return false

  for(let i = 0; i < strictlyDecreasing.length - 1; i++)
    if(!(strictlyDecreasing[i] > strictlyDecreasing[i+1])) return false
  
  return true
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Maybe using reduce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create difference graph and check for the specific pattern.

Here you can find two patterns first return condition check whether array elements follows increment and then decrement pattern.

Second return condition check whether array elements follows and decrement then increment pattern.

```js
function checkSledJump(heights) {
    let graph = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < heights.length - 1; i++) {
        const diff = heights[i + 1] - heights[i];
        if(!diff) return false;
        graph.push(diff > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    const graphString = graph.join('');

    return graphString.lastIndexOf('1') + 1 && graphString.lastIndexOf('1') < graphString.indexOf('0') ? true : false; // pattern increment => decrement
    //return graphString.lastIndexOf('0') + 1 && graphString.lastIndexOf('0') < graphString.indexOf('1')? true : false; // pattern decrement => increment
}

console.log(checkSledJump([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));        // true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([0, 1, 0]));              // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([0, 3, 2, 1]));           // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([0, 1000, 1]));           // -> true: strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([2, 4, 4, 6, 2]));        // false: [4,4] isn't strictly increasing or decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([1, 2, 3]));              // false: only increasing
console.log(checkSledJump([3, 2, 1]));              // false: only decreasing
console.log(checkSledJump([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]));  // false: increasing then decreasing then increasing
console.log(checkSledJump([1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: Interesting aproach. You missed one thing, when you do `diff > 0 ? 1 : 0` you are not differentiating between decreasing and strictly decreasing in the false branch with the zero. For example, this case `[1,2,3,2,2,1]` a false is expected but returns true. It can be fixed by adding `if(!diff) return false` in the loop. Anyway, I never would have thought of this. Thank you.